# How to docker push app (flask-python + redis) to gcr.io & deploy app to google kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, redis, google-kubernetes-engine, gcr.io

How to push my app (using python-flask + redis) to gcr.io and deploy to google kubernetes (by yaml file)?
And I want to set env variable for my app

```
import os
import redis

from flask import Flask
from flask import request, redirect, render_template, url_for
from flask import Response

app = Flask(__name__)
redis_host = os.environ['REDIS_HOST']
app.redis = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=6379, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)

# Be super aggressive about saving for the development environment.
# This says save every second if there is at least 1 change.  If you use
# redis in production you'll want to read up on the redis persistence
# model.
app.redis.config_set('save', '1 1')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        app.redis.lpush('entries', request.form['entry'])        
        return redirect(url_for('main_page'))
    else:
        entries = app.redis.lrange('entries', 0, -1)
        return render_template('main.html', entries=entries)

#Router my app by post and redirect to mainpage
@app.route('/clear', methods=['POST'])
def clear_entries():
    app.redis.ltrim('entries', 1, 0)
    return redirect(url_for('main_page'))

#use for docker on localhost
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: Hi, I'd reckon that following guides should help you to send the image to `gcr` and use it in a `Deployment`: [push image to gcr](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling), [create a Deployment](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/deployment). You will need to edit the manifest to change the image part. It will be something like this: `gcr.io/project-name/image-name`.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to set more of a baseline approach to the question rather than to give a specific solution addressing the code included in the question.

Feel free to edit/expand.

---

This topic could be quite wide considering the fact it could be addressed in many different ways (as described in the question, by using [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build), etc).

Addressing this question specifically on the part of:

- Building the image and sending it to `GCR`.
- Using newly built image in `GKE`.

---

#### Building the image and sending it to `GCR`.

Assuming that your code and your whole Docker image is running correctly, you can build/tag it in a following manner to then send it to `GCR`:

- `gcloud auth configure-docker`

> adds the Docker credHelper entry to Docker's
> configuration file, or creates the file if it doesn't exist. This will
> register gcloud as the credential helper for all Google-supported
> Docker registries.

- `docker tag YOUR_IMAGE gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME`
- `docker push gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME`

After that you can go to the:

- `GCP Cloud Console` (Web UI) -> `Container Registry`

and see the image you've uploaded.

---

#### Using newly built image in GKE

To run earlier mentioned image you can either:

- Create the `Deployment` in the `Cloud Console` (`Kubernetes Engine` -> `Workloads` -> `Deploy`)

> A side note!
>
> You can also add there the environment variables of your choosing (as pointed in the question)

- Create it with a `YAML` manifest that will be similar to the one below:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: amazing-app
  labels:
    app: amazing-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: amazing-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: amazing-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: amazing-app
        image: gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/IMAGE-NAME # <-- IMPORTANT!
        env:
        - name: DEMO_GREETING
          value: "Hello from the environment"
```

Please take a specific look on following part:

```yaml
        env:
        - name: DEMO_GREETING
          value: "Hello from the environment"
```

This part will create an environment variable inside of each container:

- `$ kubectl exec -it amazing-app-6db8d7478b-4gtxk -- /bin/bash -c 'echo $DEMO_GREETING'`

```sh
Hello from the environment
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Container registry: Docs: Pushing and pulling](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Build: Docs: Deploying builds: Deploy GKE](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-gke)*